# $wpdb->get_results() as an array of arrays

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array, resultset

I am adding an ancillary page to my wordpress site ( without the site's styling, menu, etc ) using the following template and it is not returning any results from the database. I've read countless web pages and a couple of WP books and I am at a lost. I can see the four records in the database but the page shows none. Here's my template:

> <?php 
>       /*
>           Template Name: Media Player Page
>       */ ?><!DOCTYPE html> >
>       <head>
>           <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
>           <title>Online Media Player</title>
>
> ```
>     <?php wp_head(); ?>
>
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/music-player.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
>
>     <script src="/assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>     <div class="main-center">
>         <h1>Please select your choice of music</h1>
>         <?php
>             global $wpdb;
>             $rows = $wpdb->get_results("select * from ppm_playlists");
>             foreach($rows as $row) :
>         ?>
>             <a class="openplayer"  data-genre="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $row['playlist']; ?></a>
>         <?php endforeach; ?>
>     </div> <!-- /.main-center -->
>
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>         (function($) {
>             $('.main-center').on('click', '.openplayer', function(e){
>                 var genre = $(this).data('genre');
>                 e.preventDefault();
>                 alert(genre);
>             });
>         })(jQuery);
>     </script>
> </body> </html>
> ```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have javascript mixed in with html and mixed with php? all inside a template... last time i checked thats not how you make a template inside wordpress

Comment: only way I could think to make it work. It's a page that is powered from the database which is edited via a plug-in and there is no post information needed for the page. It was just easier to include everything in one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$wpdb->get_results` will return an array of objects](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results), not an array of arrays, unless you pass it a second parameter instructing otherwise. If you had [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), you would see `Fatal Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array....`

You want to be using object syntax:

```
foreach($rows as $row) : ?>
  <a class="openplayer"  data-genre="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $row->playlist; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or pass a second parameter to `get_results`

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("select * from ppm_playlists", ARRAY_A);
```